# PHP column to line in arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have come to this part of script so far:

```
dif($result>0)
{
    $ii=0;
    $jj=0;
    while (odbc_fetch_row($result))
    {
        for ($jj = 1; $jj <= odbc_num_fields($result); $jj++)
        {
            $rr[$ii][$jj]=odbc_result($result,$jj);
            if(is_null($rr[$ii][$jj]))
                $rr[$ii][$jj] = noData;
            echo $rr[$ii][$jj];
            echo "<br />";
            }
        $ii++;
    }
}
```

This works good for creating and populating dynamic tables. But i need also to create dynamic number of single line arrays which consist of column values of arrays i get previously.
Example:

if i get

```
Array1
2012.01.01 10 20 30
2012.01.02 1 2 3
2012.01.03 11 22 33
```

i need to convert to

```
Array2
2012.01.01 2012.01.02 2012.01.03
Array3
10 1 11
Array4
20 2 22
Array5
30 3 33
```

As i mentioned before the first part of script is needed, so is there a possibility to use result to create single line arrays for further use? I suppose i'm missing something...

Comment: format your code and results.

Comment: very bad question post. Format your code at least

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is wrong with a for loop and adding the elements to an array?'

```
$rr = array(array(1,2,3,4,5),array(6,7,8,9,0),array(11,22,33,44,55));

$result = array();

for($j=0;$j<count($rr[0]);$j++){
    $col = array();
    for($i=0;$i<count($rr);$i++) {
        array_push($col,$rr[$i][$j]);
    }
    array_push($result,$col);
}

print_r($result);
```

for a demo see this codepad: http://codepad.org/wgSCtoMV